# Flask SQLAlchemy AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

I have sucessfully created a User at `login`, and now I'm querying it:

```
user = User.query.filter_by(restaurant=session['user']).first()
```

`user` prints:

```
<ID 1>, <User u'Big Burger'>, <Username u'me'>, <Email me@mac.com'>
```

At this point, I'm trying to create and `append` objects to `user`, like so:

```
burger = Menu('cheeseburger')

db.session.add(burger)
db.session.commit()

user.menu.append(burger)
```

and I get:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'

but how do It get this `NoneType` traceback if `burger` prints:

```
<Items u'cheeseburger'>
```

?

**models.py**

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__='user'
    """
    Model for storing user data. 
    """
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    restaurant = db.Column(db.String(50))
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)

    menu = db.relationship("Menu",
                    backref=db.backref('user'), uselist=False)


    def __init__(self, restaurant, username, email):
        self.restaurant = restaurant
        self.username = username
        self.email = email


    def __repr__(self):
        return '<ID %r>, <User %r>, <Username %r>, <Email %r>' % (self.id,                                                                      self.restaurant,                                                                      self.username,                                                                      self.email)

    @property
    def serialize(self):
       """Return object data in easily serializeable format"""
       return { 'id' : self.id,
                'mail' : self.email,
                'restaurant' : self.restaurant,
                'username' : self.username,
                'menu' : self.menu }

class Menu(db.Model):
    __tablename__='menu'
    """
    Model for storing menus. 
    """

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    items = db.Column(db.String(50))    
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))

    def __init__(self, items):
        self.items = items


    def __repr__(self):
        return '<items %r>' % (self.items)

    @property
    def serialize(self):
       """Return object data in easily serializeable format"""
       return { 'items' : self.items }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's user.menu that doesn't have the append attribute, not burger. Switching uselist to True will help you:

```
menu = db.relationship("Menu", backref=db.backref('user'), uselist=True)
burgers = [str(m.items) for m in menu]
```

Now burgers should have what you seek.

Comment: it kinda works. but `'menu': [<Items u'cheesburger'>]}` gets added. how do I serialize ir correctly in order to add the string `u'cheesburger'` only?